# Dealership won't communicate with me, at all. Any advice?

Tags: ford

My Ford truck broke down five days ago (alternator trouble).  I had it towed to my Ford dealership and confirmed with the towing company that the tow was completed.  I called the dealership beforehand so they were aware.

Now, five days later, I cannot get anyone at the dealership to speak to me.  I have called the service rep 3 days ago but had to leave a message on his answering machine.  No callback.

I went on to their website and got a live person to chat with, who suggested I contact the service manager, so I tried and of course-- answering machine.  No callback.

I went on to their website again the operator assured me they would send "hot alert" messages to have the dealership contact me.  I gave them my phone number again, noting that the dealership already has it.  I am not a new customer.

I don't know what to do now.  I don't know what would cause a dealership to become totally unresponsive to my requests for communication.

Does anyone, possibly someone who worked at a dealership, have an insight into what the problem could be?  I thought it pretty reasonable to expect *some* kind of communication sooner than 5 days.  Should I wait longer?  Keep leaving messages to no avail?  File a police report?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  My suggestion to you is to contact the General Manager of the dealership. The GM is responsible for the entire dealership, including the service department.

Comment: Did they close for a long break ?

Comment: @ Paulster2:  I tried that, too.  But all I got was the GM's answering machine, which is all you ever get.

Comment: @ Solar Mike:  No, they have been open all week.  Closed on on Labor Day itself, according to their website.  I did get an automated sales email this morning though, saying "Thanks for your interest in  ___" and the form letter had no model listed, which makes sense given that I didn't visit the sales portion of their site at all.  But it had the phone number of the salesman.  Maybe I could get a live human if I pretended to be interested in buying?

Comment: +1. Welcome to stack exchange! Yes maybe call the sales department and when you are talking to a live human get them to help you get in touch with the GM.

Comment: Go to the dealership and confront the General Manager!

Comment: Yah, in person may be your best bet.

Comment: Don’t raise your voice, yet be assertive.